# Answer the call automatically in android (Marshmallow)

Tags: android

In my project I have to receive the call automatically in  marshmallow. I referred internet but still i haven't got the solution

Here is the code:

```
public void acceptCall() {
    Toast.makeText(context,"inside accept call",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,
            new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
}
```

Permission in  manifest:

I also have done runtime permission for marshmallow.

Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: For this you have to add marshmallow permission.

Comment: I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make a request for permission of call_phone before doing any thing. To be in the safe side.
(Don't forget to put this permission in manifest)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

and java code for checking will be like this:

```
int checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
if (checkPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
        } else {
            customDialog(CallChoosyActivity.this);
        }
```

Comment: Here you are just giving the runtime permission which is required in marshmallow..and permission in manifest file...that i also have done...what is the code to receive the call automatically?

Comment: Did you find anything? I have been trying to find the solution since 2 days still none of the code works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use telephone manager to listen for incoming calls, you can read more about it from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)

```
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = null;
        PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() 
        {
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
            {
                switch (state) 
                {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
               // call ended
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                  // call picked
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                   // call is ringing now
try {
telephonyManager.getClass().getMethod("answerRingingCall").invoke(telephonyManager);
} catch (Exception e) { 

}
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        // Register the listener with the telephony manager
        telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: Not working, it seems you can only find out the state of the call but you can't accept it automatically.